# MongoDB whereIn cannot be used with other queries in Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.2, MongoDb ([jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)).
I have this code:

```
$query = $query->where('av_time_from', '<', $request->get('available_time'))->where('av_time_to', '>', $request->get('available_time'))->whereIn('location',$request->get('locations'))->get();
```

I run this query and dump out the query before `paginated(dump($query);)`.
But that query consists of `whereIn`:

```
wheres: array:1 [
    0 => array:4 [
        "type" => "In"
        "column" => "location"
        "values" => array:2 [
            0 => "58087de0d5ae4108ac40c412"
            1 => "5809d754d5ae4108ac40c419"
        ]
        "boolean" => "and"
    ]
]
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: you can check your query by making a mistake in column name

Comment: @GauravGupta I have changed av_time_from and av_time_to as foo1 and foo2. But the query is same as before.

Comment: What is the problem? you don't need that whereIn?

Comment: i mean it show you error in error there is complete query with wrong name
error like column not found

Comment: @MortezaRajabi I need that whereIn because $request->get('locations') is array of multiple checkboxes.

Comment: @YeLu I didn't understand what your problem is?

Comment: @MortezaRajabi where('av_time_from', '<', $request->get('available_time'))->where('av_time_to', '>', $request->get('available_time')) works only itself but not working when used together with that whereIn.

Comment: And how did you create the $query?

Comment: @MortezaRajabi $query = Shop::query();

Comment: I checked your query, and it is working as you need!

Comment: @MortezaRajabi So, why two where query info are not contained in the that where array? In really those where query is not working.